# Splitting field of a sixth degree polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the polynomial $f(T)=T^6-11T^4+36T^2-36$, and I'm asked to find out if it has at least a root in $\Bbb Q$: for the rational root theorem I just calculated $f(36)$ and $f(-36)$ to conclude that $f(T)$ is not reducible over $\Bbb Q$. (Right?)

Then I'm asked to find out for which primes $p$ the polynomial $f(T)$ has a root in $\Bbb F_p$; how do I have to proceed?

Comment: Thinking of $f(T)$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ means taking the coefficients mod $p$. So for example what happens when you go mod 3?

Comment: Read about the rational root theorem again.  Checking 36 and $-36$ is not enough.  36 is not a prime number!

Comment: And even if $36$ were (replaced by) a prime number you always would need to check $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not having a root is necessary but not sufficient (for degree $\geq 4$) condition for irreducibility of a polynomial.

**Hint**: $f(T)$ is a cubic polynomial in $T^2$, and you can check
$$
f(T)=(T^2)^3-11(T^2)^2+36(T^2)-36=(T^2-2)(T^2-3)(T^2-6)
$$
So what does $2\times 3=6$ tell you?

Comment: Of course only one of the actual rational roots need to be trialed.  The rest are resolved from the residual quadratic factor.

Comment: thank you I didn't realize that $f(T)$ could be factorized like that

Comment: However, how do I find out which fields $F_p$ contain a square root of $2$ and $3$?

Comment: @Dorian That is the purpose of the last sentence in hint.  What does $2\times 3=6$ tell you?  Can $2,3,6$ all be quadratic nonresidues?

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out; since $\sqrt2$  and $\sqrt3$ don't generate a cyclic subgroup of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_p$ (like for example $i$ does), I can't make assumptions about $p-1$ (the order of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_p$).

Comment: It's clear that if I consider the polynomial over $\Bbb F_2$ or $\Bbb F_3$ it is reducible, but maybe is reducible over other $\Bbb F_p$ too